# Openstack Newton Glance Error during db_sync

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

During the initial configuration of Glance, while running:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "glance-manage db_sync" glance`
```

I get the following error:

```
2017-07-18 12:14:04.381 14001 INFO glance.db.sqlalchemy.migrate_repo.schema [-] creating table image_members
2017-07-18 12:14:05.095 14001 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] done
2017-07-18 12:14:05.095 14001 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] 8 -> 9...
2017-07-18 12:14:05.819 14001 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] done
2017-07-18 12:14:05.820 14001 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] 9 -> 10...
2017-07-18 12:14:05.861 14001 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] done
2017-07-18 12:14:05.861 14001 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] 10 -> 11...
2017-07-18 12:14:06.494 14001 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] done
2017-07-18 12:14:06.494 14001 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] 11 -> 12...
2017-07-18 12:14:06.604 14001 CRITICAL glance [-] ArgumentError: Column type VARCHAR(36) on column 'images.id' is not compatible with autoincrement=True
```

Is anyone able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: please upgrade sqlalchemy-migrate to 0.11.0 to resolve this issue.

Credit goes to Mike Bayer.

====

I just met exactly the same bug.

It turns out downgrading SQLAlchemy from 1.1 to 1.0 solves the issue.

After you do `sudo pip uninstall sqlalchemy && sudo pip install sqlalchemy==1.0`

Just run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure glance-common`

to reconfigure the glance upgrading script.

I submitted a bug on glance bug tracker here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/glance/+bug/1723097

And an email in SQLAlchemy mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/xoBcc6UnpWo